# Bootstrap odd number of spans - 7 thumbnail images on bottom

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Maybe I'm over thinking this.. How can I have an odd number of thumbnails using Bootstrap's grid.  I have 7 thumbnail images at the bottom.  I'd like to space them out of course using the grid.  Maybe this isn't possible and should just use regular CSS?

Here's what I tried:

```
               <div class="row-fluid">
                <div class="span12">
                 <ul class="thumbnails">
                    <li class="span1">
                        <div class="thumbnail">
                            <img src="img/diningroom/1.jpg" alt="">
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <li class="span2">
                        <div class="thumbnail">
                            <img src="img/diningroom/2.jpg" alt="">
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <li class="span2">
                        <div class="thumbnail">
                            <img src="img/diningroom/3.jpg" alt="">
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <li class="span2">
                        <div class="thumbnail">
                            <img src="img/diningroom/4.jpg" alt="">
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <li class="span2">
                        <div class="thumbnail">
                            <img src="img/diningroom/5.jpg" alt="">
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <li class="span2">
                        <div class="thumbnail">
                            <img src="img/diningroom/6.jpg" alt="">
                        </div>
                    </li>
                     <li class="span1">
                        <div class="thumbnail">
                            <img src="img/diningroom/6.jpg" alt="">
                        </div>
                    </li>

                </ul>
              </div>
              </div>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can customize bootstrap columns [here](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/customize.html#variables) (see @gridColumns).

Comment: You're right!  How would this work if I wanted to keep all my other pages to the standard 12 grid and just use the 14 grid for my gallery?

Comment: you will have to inspect the bootstrap less code. if you manage less you can generate two different files (eg: bootstrap12columns.css and bootstrap14columns.css).